# How to plot using openGL using user-given values / asking for values?

Tags: objective-c, opengl, plot, glut

**Limitations:**

- I can't change the frameworks
- I have to use the functions in the
  program (my beloved teacher doesn't like us using functions given by any other than herself)

Here's the code and it works just like this (just not as smooth as i would like it to)

```
#include<OpenGL/gl.h>
#include<OpenGL/glu.h>
#include<GLUT/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int lb=-30, ub=30;
double cpoints=9999999;

void init (void)
{
    glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(-30,30,-30,30);
}

void graphfunct2D(void)
{
    double dx, xi, yi;
    dx = (ub-lb)*1.0/cpoints;
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    xi = lb;
    yi = xi*sin(xi);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<=cpoints;i++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i(xi,yi);
        glEnd();
        xi = xi+dx;
        yi = xi*sin(xi);
    }
    glFlush();
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    /*printf("lower bound: ");
    scanf(" %d",&lb);
    printf("upper bound:");
    scanf(" %d",&ub);
    printf("Give me the number of points to plot (int)");
    scanf(" %d",&cpoints);*/
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutCreateWindow("Graph function in 2D");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(graphfunct2D);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

I want the user to be able to provide the upper and lower bounds and plot the function based on those two but when i run the program with the inputs uncommented it doesnt display anything (when i dont ask for them and use the ones i defined it runs just fine)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean "it doesn't display anything?" Do you mean it doesn't display the prompt to enter the upper and lower bounds, or that after the user has entered them, it doesn't display the results?

Comment: @user1118321 i mean the program starts (it keeps jumping on the dock like it's starting but it doesn't actually start/display the window/stop jumping) this happens when i run it from the compiler, when i run it from terminal it does ask for the bounds and number of points to plot but displays a blank window (i'm getting some warnings tho:

Comment: `func2d.h: In function ‘main’:
func2d.h:49: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
func2d.h:50: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘scanf’
func2d.h:54: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’`

Comment: edit: it's solved now thank you guys it works when i gcc it from terminal, however if there's a way to make it run from the compiler it would be nice for me to learn how to do it too if not thank you anyway
ps. it's not homework :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double lb=-30, ub=30;
unsigned int cpoints=2048;
void graphfunct2D(void)
{
    double dx, xi, yi;
    int i;
    dx = (ub-lb)/cpoints;

    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -30, 30, -30, 30, -1, 1 );
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3ub(0,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for( i = 0; i <= cpoints; i++ )
    {
        xi = (i * dx) + lb;
        yi = xi * sin(xi);
        glVertex2f( xi, yi );
    }
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("lower bound: ");
    scanf(" %d",&lb);
    printf("upper bound:");
    scanf(" %d",&ub);
    printf("Give me the number of points to plot (int)");
    scanf(" %d",&cpoints);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutCreateWindow("Graph function in 2D");
    glutDisplayFunc(graphfunct2D);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! this worked when i ran it from terminal :D i think there might be a problem with scans from xcode i'll probably have to look into that too later but for now this will do just a quick question what does the function LoadIdentity() do? ty again

Comment: [`glLoadIdentity()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml) overwrites the top of the current matrix stack with a 4x4 [identity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix).  For non-terminal usage look into [application bundles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_bundle#Mac_OS_X_application_bundles) if you aren't already using one.

Comment: Thank you i'll take a look at those bundle thingies for sure